Inconsistent behavior in low-quality review queue with comment votes
I recently completed a couple of Low-Quality-Post reviews on Science-Fiction & Fantasy.
The one that turned up first allowed me to upvote the comment there.
The second one to turn up did not allow me to upvote the comment there. Every time I tried, the page jumped to the top, very annoying.
I've observed this behavior for some while (on multiple sites) and am mindful of Visual design changes to the review queues from 2021:

We heard from you that being able to vote directly on all tasks as
well as the option to follow posts and receive updates on changes
would help in the reviewing process. These features will be available
in all queues.

Expected behavior: Well, I'd prefer to be able to consistently vote on comments please, but consistency either way.

It sounds like this bug still

Ah, a duplicate then. If I'd been a coder then maybe I'd have known the search terms, thanks for finding that. @toolic

You're welcome.  I wish they would fix it or at least acknowledge that it is a problem by adding one of the "status" tags as has been done on MSO.
